# Android - Connection to my website

Tags: android

I spent hours looking for a code that would allow me to get connected (logged in) to my website within my app. I tried `android-async-http` library and also `android-query` but nothing helped.

Let me explain: I have a website to handle accounts between friends or whatever and all the functions are written for Ajax (and return results in JSON). It's like having an API that I can use for my app, isn't it ?

The problem is that I need to get connected (logged in). How do I keep the connection alive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an awesome tutorial 
i think this might help :)

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Comment: I saw the whole video, seems great ! :)
I'm gonna try it and i let you know if i have some troubles :)
Thanks for the link

Comment: sorryyy for being late, it works perfectly !!! :D !!!
It keeps the session and i'm able to handle JSON so just perfect !